# Why strtok() splits string that i didn't even passed to it?

Tags: c, string, split, linked-list, strtok

I need to separate string from file. String = "21:12:36 14:45:25 08:17:24"
When i do strtok() and put all tokens to array everything works fine, but when I do strtok() second time, it messes everything.
Example:

```
char *p = strtok (code, " ");
while (p != NULL){
    dal[i++] = p;
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
```

Output:

```
dal[0] = 21:12:36
dal[1] = 14:45:25
dal[2] = 08:17:24
```

I do copy of **dal** array, and when I do strtok for second time i changes my original string(code) and my copy of **dal** even I pass dal array only to strtok(). I tried to send **dal** to LinkedList, but after second strtok even LinkedList is changed.

Declaration:

```
char *dal[20], *dalcopy[20];
//copying below
for(int k = 0; k<i; k++){
    dalcopy[v] = dal[k];
    v = v+1;
}
```

Example:

```
for (int j = 0; j<i; j++){
    char *o = strtok(dal[j], ":");
    while (o != NULL){
        for(int h = 0; h<3; h++){
            if(h == 0){vienas[b].Hour = atoi(o);}
            if(h == 1){vienas[b].Min = atoi(o);}
            if(h == 2){vienas[b].Sec = atoi(o);}
            o = strtok (NULL, ":");
        }            
        b = b+1;
    }
```

LinkedList example:

```
char *p = strtok (code, " ");
while (p != NULL){
    dal[i++] = p;
    put(head, p); //puts each element to list end
    p = strtok (NULL, " ");
}
printf("%s\n", show_by_index(&head, 0)); **Output == 21 after second strtok**
```

Output:

```
original string = 21
dal[0] = 21
dal[1] = 14
dal[2] = 08
dalcopy[0] = 21
etc...
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: Your question seems to be lacking crucial bits of code. How are `dal` and `dalcopy` declared? *How* is `dalcopy` created? Copying an array of pointers doesn't copy the data that those pointers are pointing to. I suspect that `dalcopy` is an array of aliases.

Comment: `char *dal[20], *dalcopy[20];` - dal declaration
`dalcopy[0] = dal[0];`

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Too much is not shown.

Comment: By the way `dalcopy[0] = dal[0];` shows that my hunch was right. You are creating aliases for the same string rather than copies of the string. You need to `malloc` storage for the copy and then use `strcpy`. `strtok` is a destructive function and you aren't creating genuine copies which are safe from that destruction.

Comment: This might help. But why this function touches LinkedList items?

Comment: shouldn't your declarations of dal and dalcopy be: `char dal[20], dalcopy[20];`

Comment: @bruceg No. `dal` (as well as `dalcopy`)  should be a array of pointers because `strtok` returns pointers.

Comment: but the line: `dalcopy[v] = dal[k];` is just copying pointers to the same strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main things you've fo keep in mind are:

1. `strtok` is a destrutive function as said by [@JohnColeman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman) in the comments. This means that **`strtok` modifies the string (first argument) passed to it**.
2. **`strtok` gives you *pointers* that point to different parts of the string** and you store them in the array `dal`. Now, you create another similar array of pointers `dalcopy` (assuming you fixed [what @David told you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603522/3049655)) and make them point to the same parts of the string `code` as `dal` does.

`dal` and `dalcopy` point to the same tokens of the string `code`. So, any change you make to them will also affect `code` as they point to it.

Before `strtok` and everything:

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| dal[0] | dal[1] | dal[2] | dal[3] | ... = dal
+--------+--------+--------+--------+

+------------------------------+
| "21:12:36 14:45:25 08:17:24" | = code
+------------------------------+
```

After `strtok` and "copying":

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| dal[0] | dal[1] | dal[2] | dal[3] | ... = dal
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
   ↓         ↓          ↓
+---------------------------------+
| "21:12:36\0014:45:25\008:17:24" | = code
+---------------------------------+
   ↑         ↑          ↑
   |          \         \----\
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| dalcopy[0] | dalcopy[1] | dalcopy[2] | dalcopy[3] | ... = dalcopy
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

As you can see, you were not copying it, but merely creating an alias.

The solution would be to `strdup`/`malloc`+`strcpy` the tokens.

Comment: +rep Good job! Very appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *dal[20], dalcopy[20];
//copying below
for(int k = 0; k<i; k++){
    dalcopy[v] = dal[k];
    v = v+1;
 }
```

This can't be right. Since `dalcopy` is an array of characters, `dalcopy[v]` is a character. But `dal[k]` is not a character (since `dal` is an array of pointers to characters), so this assignment makes no sense at all.

Comment: And fixing the declaration would just run into the aliasing problem.

Comment: This is why you should always post complete, compilable code that you have confirmed replicates the issue you're asking about.

Comment: Your answer now doesn't make sense as the OP changed his/her code.